# Is it possible to virtualize a single process?

Tags: containers, virtual-machine, x86-64, intel, virtualization

I'm looking for a way to effectively virtualize a single process (and, presumably, any children it creates).  Although a Container model sounds appropriate, products like Docker don't quite fit the bill.

The Intel VMX model allows one to create a hypervisor, then launch a VM, which will exit back to the hypervisor under certain (programmable) conditions, such as privileged instruction execution, CR3/CR8 manipulation, exceptions, direct I/O, etc.  The features of the VMX model fit very well with my needs, except that I can't require a VM with a separate instance of the entire OS to accomplish the task - I just want my hypervisor to control one child application (think Photoshop/Excel/Firefox;  one process and its progeny, if any) that's running under the host OS, and catch VM exits under the specified conditions (for debugging and/or emulation purposes).  Outside of the exit conditions, the child process should run unencumbered, and have access to all OS resources to which it would be entitled without the VM, including filesystem, graphical output, keyboard/mouse input, IPC/messaging, etc.  For my purposes, I am not interested in isolation or access restriction, which is the typical motivation for using a VM - to the contrary, I want the child process to be fully enmeshed in the host OS environment.  While operating entirely in user-space is preferable, I can utilize Ring 0 to facilitate this.  (Note that the question is Intel-specific and OS-agnostic, although it's likely to be implemented in a *nix environment first.)

I'm wondering what would happen if I had my hypervisor set up a VMCS that simply mirrored the host's actual configuration, including page tables, IDT, etc., then VMLAUNCH 0(%rip) (in effect, a pseudo-fork?) and execute the child process from there.  (That seems far too simplistic to actually work, but the notion does have some appeal).  Assuming that's a Bad Idea™, how might I approach this problem?

Comment: "I am not interested in isolation or access restriction"   ...   So what are you interested in? What is your purpose in using virtualization?

Comment: If your application is running in a VM and it can perform system calls without causing a VM exit, now the OS is also running in the VM. When the OS schedules another process, now that process is also running in  the VM.

Comment: @prl - The purpose of using virtualization here is to trap exceptions and certain instructions, such as cpuid, from a user-space application that is not under my control (i.e. I only have binaries, no source modifications are possible).  Pre- Ivy Bridge, Intel CPUs did not have a good way to trap cpuid, but the VMX model explicitly does just that.  I understand that the VMX model may not be able to do quite what I want it to, but I thought it was an option worth exploring.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining. I agree using VMX does seem like a plausible way to do this. You can trap on ring transitions to avoid the problem described in my other comment.